# Misuse of Scala or Eclipse Bug use of Implicits

Tags: scala

I have a Class defined below:

```
class NDArray[T](data: List[List[T]])(implicit num: Numeric[T])
 .....
```

I have an object that creates and returns a new NDArray:

```
object Foo
{
   def apply() =
   {
      new NDArray(List(List())
   }
}
```

I am getting the following error:
not enough arguments for constructor NDArray: (implicit num: Numeric[A])com.numscal.matrix.NDArray[A]. Unspecified value parameter num.

I've tried importing Numeric in the object that creates the NDArray, but that doesn't work. My unit tests for NDArray don't import Numeric and they don't have any issues.

I am confused as to what is going on.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be an issue with the object being in a different package than the class?

Answer (score 4):

`data` is a list of lists of type `T`. The constructor of `NDArray` requires an object of type `Numeric[T]`. Because that parameter is declared `implicit`, that means that you don't need to specify one explicitly when the compiler can find one in the currently visible scope that also has been defined as `implicit`.

Now, since you create an instance of `NDArray` without specifying `T`, the compiler infers `T`. It finds the list of lists, and uses the element type of the inner list as `T`. But since you did not specify that one and the list is empty, this defaults to being a `List[Nothing]`, therefore, the compiler concludes that `T` is the type `Nothing`.

Then it searches for an `implicit` instance of `Numeric[Nothing]`, but that does not exist.

There are several things you can do. Either:

```
new NDArray(List(List[Int]()))
```

Or:

```
new NDArray[Int](List(List()))
```

(Although I'm not sure if that last one is gonna work. I don't know if the compiler will infer the type parameter of the inner list correctly; you just have to try it.)

The `implicit` instance of `Numeric[Int]` is already imported by default, since it is part of `Predef`. You don't need to import it explicitly. The same goes for all primitive numeric types.

I don't know if you want to use a list of lists of integers, or floats, or whatever. The compiler does not know either, and it can't infer because the list you have given is empty.

Comment: That makes sense. I see some things that I need to change in my code.  thank you for the detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> List(List())
res19: List[List[Nothing]] = List(List())
```

There is no implicit Numeric for `Nothing`, use `List.empty[List[TypeYouNeed]]`

Comment: Ok... Now lets change that to List(List(1,2,3)) -- My mistake I didn't see that I left it empty.